# Any way to get details on a collaborator's identity from the Box API?

Tags: box-api

The closest thing I can get are events that show a "COLLAB_ADD_COLLABORATOR" type of event - however, this does not include the collaborator's identity.

Note that I want this information potentially before this user does anything to a file or folder: I simply want to get a list of all collaborators whether or not they have performed any actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use V1 of the API to fetch the collabs of each folder individually. This might not full-fill your requirement of knowing before the collab does anything on it. But this is your best bet right now. V2 doesnot have it yet

http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923933/ApiFunction_get_collaborations

Answer (score 0):

That information would be contained in a v2 'collaborations' object. The /collaborations endpoint currently isn't implemented for the v2 API. However, it will be implemented before v2 is GA.